# Vincular aplicación Angular a aplicación Express

Tags: angular, express

Tenemos una web corporativa hecha en Express a la cual le queremos vincular una aplicación web hecha con Angular. La landing page es la web con Express la cual contiene un botón de Iniciar Sesión que queremos que lleve al login de una aplicación web Angular. Hasta aquí todo bien pero resulta que cuando hacemos un refresh de la página en estando dentro de la aplicación Angular, se vuelve a cargar la web Express regresando a la landing page. 
Suponemos que es cuestión de configurar correctamente las rutas de express.

**Archivo server.js**

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {      
    res.render('index');
});


app.all('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/app_client/dist/softacademies/index.html'));    
});
```

Dejamos la web para que puedan reproducir lo que comentamos
https://www.softacademies.com

Muchas gracias,